# Prometheus query to return Top 5 results

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

I am running a diskspace used query in Prometheus and would like to return only the top 5 or 10 entries from the search result. Is there anyway I can achieve that?

Currently, the query I am trying is returning me 58 entries

```
(100 - 100 * (node_filesystem_avail{device!~"by-uuid",device!~"tmpfs",mountpoint="/"} / node_filesystem_size{device!~"by-uuid",device!~"tmpfs",mountpoint="/"})) > 70
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add topk(5, ...) in your query:

```
topk(5, (100 - 100 * (node_filesystem_avail{device!~"by-uuid",device!~"tmpfs",mountpoint="/"} / node_filesystem_size{device!~"by-uuid",device!~"tmpfs",mountpoint="/"})) > 70)
```